# RSpec failling in email should not be valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm new to all this rails/rspec and so on, so im trying to follow some tests that I had found in the project that i'm working and make sense, they were generated by scaffold but the app is very different and no tests were updated so im re-doing every test.

The problem is when I try to validate that invalid emails should make the user invalid it fails.
I know that it's ok because I already done tests and they pass without no problem.

It is possible that I'm looking at this the wrong way but ...

**User_spec**

```
describe "when email format is invalid" do
  it "should be invalid" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                   foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      @user.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

**User_test**

```
test "fail save new user with an corrupt email" do
  user = User.new
  user.name = 'Someone Name'
  user.password = '12345678'
  user.email = 'Someone Name@gmail..com'
  assert !user.save , "User was saved with an corrupt email"
end
```

The validation is done by devise and the failure message is "**expected valid? to return false, got true**"

---- edit ---

My user setup

```
...
describe User do
  before :each do
    @user = User.new(name: "Name of Names", email:"someone1@somewhere.com",password: "foobarfoobar", password_confirmation: "foobarfoobar" )
  end
...
```

Comment: For a start, try checking each address individually to see which one isn't being recognized as invalid.

Comment: I already test with one of them at a time the test fails on all of them

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along the lines of this:

```
context "validations" do
  describe "email" do
    subject { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: email) }

    context "with an valid address" do
      let(:email) { "valid@email.com" }

      it { should be_valid }
    end

    context "with an invalid email address" do
      let(:email) { "invalid.email.com" }

      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

So I'm assuming you are using [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to create an valid user object. Just create new tests per invalid email, this way you can see which tests are passing and which aren't. Then you could TDD your way to green.

Comment: No you don't have to, you just need to supply an _valid_ user object to the subject. But make sure to keep the email: email part. You could do something like this subject { User.new(first_name: "Miguel", age: 26, email: email) }. the let(:email) blocks will be evaluated in the email variable in the subject.

Comment: I edited the question with the user setup, its the same as yours.

Comment: make it like this: before { let(:user) { User.new(name: "Name of Names", email: email ,password: "foobarfoobar", password_confirmation: "foobarfoobar") }. Now you can just use let(:email) { "someinvalid.email.com" } in your tests and test against those emails.